# How to add check condition if student already paid the fee of current moth in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to add check condition if student paid the fee of current month so I want to show message the student fee is already paid

```
    public ActionResult EditFees(StudentMV studentMV)
    {
        string currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
            var check = DB.tblStudents.Where(s => s.AdmissionNO == studentMV.AdmissionNO && s.FeeID != studentMV.FeeID && s.tblFee.Date == DateTime.Now).FirstOrDefault();
            if (check == null )
            {
                var checkstudent = DB.tblStudents.Find(studentMV.StudentID);

                checkstudent.StudentID = studentMV.StudentID;
                checkstudent.AdmissionNO = studentMV.AdmissionNO;
                checkstudent.Name = studentMV.Name;
                checkstudent.FatherName = studentMV.FatherName;
                checkstudent.tblFee.FeeID = studentMV.FeeID;
                checkstudent.tblFee.AdmissionFee = studentMV.AdmissionFee;
                checkstudent.tblFee.TutionFee = studentMV.TutionFee;
                checkstudent.tblFee.Stationary = studentMV.Stationary;
                checkstudent.tblFee.SportFee = studentMV.SportFee;
                checkstudent.tblFee.Received = studentMV.Received;
                checkstudent.tblFee.Balance = studentMV.Balance;
                checkstudent.tblFee.Date = studentMV.Date;
                DB.Entry(checkstudent).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                DB.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Fees");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("TutionFee", "Already Paid!");

            }

        
        return View(studentMV);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the date condition from the LINQ query

```
s.tblFee.Date == DateTime.Now;
```

Add below condition in Query

```
s.tblFee.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && s.tblFee.Year == DateTime.Now.Year;
```

We need to check the current month as well as year also, otherwise, it gives an error while next year you are paid a fees in your portal

Comment: s.tblFee.Month so i have to create the month and year colum in tblFee?

Comment: No, you don't need to create, if tblFee datatype is date-time then you can directly use it .Date